# ¿Leer un archivo txt linea por linea y dejarlo disponible en un puerto TCP SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tcp

tengo el siguiente código que lee un archivo de texto desde una carpeta y lo copia a otra carpeta pero necesito leer el archivo linea por linea y dejarlo disponible en un puerto tcp, pensaba usar Sockets.

```
public class IntegrationConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Transformer transformer;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow(){
        return IntegrationFlows.from(fileReader(),spec -> spec.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(500)))
                .transform(transformer,"transform")
                .handle(fileWriter())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public FileWritingMessageHandler fileWriter() {
        FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(
                new File("destination")
        );
        handler.setExpectReply(false);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public FileReadingMessageSource fileReader() {
        FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        source.setDirectory(new File("files"));
        return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: HOla. ¿Qué problema tienes con este código?

Comment: Como puedo hacer para que en vez de copiar el archivo txt a otra carpeta poderlo poner en un puerto tcp

Comment: ¿Qué significa para ti *ponerlo disponible en un puerto TCP*?

Comment: osea que un cliente pueda consumir esa información, osea si paso la primera linea del txt que otro componente pueda usarlo y modificarlo mendiante TCP.

Comment: con el codigo que pusiste no se hace ni remotamente nada de lo que quieres te sugiero itnentarlo y derivado de eso agregar un [mcve] con lo que tengas problemas en tu implementacion

Comment: No vandalices tu propia pregunta, en todo caso puedes eliminarla.

Comment: Pues... de poderse, seguro se puede. Hay que mirar si te importa la concurrencia o no, si simplemente envías una línea del archivo y la recibes modificada y la cambias en el archivo, si debes ocuparte de ver qué pasa si le envías la línea del archivo a un cliente y se interrumpe la comunicación, etc. Faltan cosas por revisar :)